# List directories in Linux based on inclusion and exclusion of specific files

Tags: linux, bash, directory, find

Short version:

I'm trying to write a bash command that will produce a list of sub directories based on the presence and/or absence of certain files.  The directory name would be in included the list if it contains the file named "Ready" and does not contain the files named "Complete" or "Failed". I've been futzing around with the 'find' command based on examples I've seen here, but I don't have a good enough grasp of it or bash in general to make it work.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name Ready | find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/Complete" ';' -print | find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/Failed" ';' -print
```

Long version:

In our system another group drops off directories of files ("bundles") that are processed by one of our applications.  These directories can contain one or more zero-length status files that specify that the bundle is ready for processing ("Ready") or should be ignored since it was either successfully processed ("Completed") or there was previously an error ("Failed").

Most of the system is purchased software, and we're starting to develop some home-grown monitoring, administration, and metrics-gathering tools. I'm trying to write a script that will look at these directories at any given time and determine, based on the presence or absence of the status files, which of them are ready for processing and which will be ignored.

Comment: Piping `find` into `find` isn't meaningful. Use one `find` with multiple `-exec` statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash` 4 or later, I would skip `find` and iterate over the recursive glob `**/*/`.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for d in **/*/; do
  [[ -e $d/Ready ]] || continue  # Skip directories without a Ready file
  [[ -e $d/Completed ]] && continue  # Skip directories with a Completed file
  [[ -e $d/Failed ]] && continue  # Skip directories with a Failed file
  print '%s\n' "$d"  # If you made it this far, print the directory name
done
```

This can be condensed to

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for d in **/*/; do
  [[ -e $d/Ready && ! (-e $d/Completed || -e $d/Failed) ]] && printf '%s\n' "$d"
done
```

You could alternatively use the glob to identify those directories containing `Ready`:

```
for f in **/*/Ready; do
  d=${f%Ready}
  [[ -e $d/Completed || -e $d/Failed ]] || printf '%s\n' "$d"
done
```

Comment: Works pretty good.  One problem -- until we get some kind of data retention policy implemented, there can be alot of files in subdirectories to recurse through, which may make the script run longer than I want for a quick utility.  We would only need to look one directory level down from the starting point, anything below that can be ignored.  Any way to do that?

Comment: In that case, you can just use `*/*/` instead of `**/*`, and you don't need the `globstar` option (and this will work in all versions of `bash`, not just 4+).

Comment: Removing the "globstar" option and using a single "*" works for me (*/*/ did not).  Thanks the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` with the option to `not` match certain names:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -path "*Ready*" ! -name "Failed" -a ! \
-name "Complete" -exec bash -c 'echo "$0"' {} \;
```

In nested directories `-path` would only find files within the "Ready" directory which don't contain (`!`) "Failed" or "Complete". For example:

```
$ ls
Complete Failed   Ready    outdir   sub1     sub2     sub3 

$ cd Ready ; ls
Complete Failed   Ready    somefile
```

Using the `find` command above from the parent directory would produce:

```
./Ready
./Ready/Ready
./Ready/somefile
```

If you switched `-path` to `-name` you would get:

```
./Ready
./Ready/Ready
```

`find` is a powerful utility that can be adjusted to fit almost any need when it comes to searching.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something simple.

Start with a `find` command that finds the files you use as triggers.  Pipe that into a "grep" that will get rid of the filename, sort, eliminate duplicates, something like :

```
find . -type f -name Ready -o -name Completed -o -name Failed | grep -o "^.*/" | sort | uniq
```

Add `-maxdepth 2 -mindepth` 2 before `-type f` to limite depth to 1 level.